# Rudin proof of theorem 2.14 RCA inequality explanation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

This is the last step of Rudin's proof for Riesz representation theorem. However I do not understand how he has deducted the (1) and (2) inequalities in the last part of the step.
Related question: [Riesz Representation Theorem, Rudin: Real and complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884250/riesz-representation-theorem-rudin-real-and-complex-analysis?rq=1)

> **Proof.**
>   Clearly, it is enough to prove this for real $f$.
>   Also, it is enough to prove the *inequality*
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tag{16}
>        \Lambda f
>   \leq \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu
> \end{equation}
>   for every real $f \in C_c(X)$.
>   For once $(16)$ is established, the linearity of $\Lambda$ shows that
>   $$
>        -\Lambda f
>   =    \Lambda(-f)
>   \leq \int_X (-f) \,\mathrm{d}\mu
>   =    - \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu,
> $$
>   which, together with $(16)$ shows that equality holds in $(16)$.
>
> Let $K$ be the support of the real $f \in C_c(X)$, let $[a,b]$ be an interval which contains the range of $f$ (note the Corollary to Theorem 2.10), choose $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $y_i$, for $i = 0, 1, \dotsc, n$, so that $y_i - y_{i-1} < \epsilon$ and
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tag{17}
>   y_0 < a < y_1 < \dotsb < y_n = b.
> \end{equation}
>   Put
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tag{18}
>     E_i
>   = \{ x : y_{i-1} < f(x) \leq y_i \} \cap K
>   \qquad
>   (i = 1, \dotsc, n)
> \end{equation}
>   Since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is Borel measurable, and the sets $E_i$ are therefore disjoint Borel sets whose union is $K$.
>   There are open sets $V_i \supset E_i$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tag{19}
>     \mu(V_i)
>   < \mu(E_i) + \frac{\epsilon}{n}
>   \qquad
>   (i = 1, \dotsc, n)
> \end{equation}
>   and such that $f(x) < y_i + \epsilon$ for all $x \in V_i$.
>   By Theorem 2.13, there are functions $h_i \prec V_i$ such that $\sum h_i = 1$ on $K$.
>   Hence $f = \sum h_i f$, and Step II shows that
>   $$
>        \mu(K)
>   \leq \Lambda\left( \sum h_i \right)
>   =    \sum \Lambda h_i.
> $$
>   Since $h_i f \leq (y_i + \epsilon) h_i$, and since $y_i - \epsilon < f(x)$ on $E_i$, we have
>   \begin{align*}
>         \Lambda f
>   &=    \sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda(h_i f)
>    \leq \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i + \epsilon) \Lambda h_i \\
>   &=    \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon) \Lambda h_i
>         - |a| \sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda h_i \\
>  (1) &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon)[ \mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n ]       
>         - |a| \mu(K) \\
>   &=    \sum_{i=1}^n (y _i - \epsilon) \mu(E_i)
>         + 2 \epsilon \mu(K)
>         + \frac{\epsilon}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon) \\        
>  (2) &\leq \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu
>         + \epsilon[ 2\mu(K) + |a| + b + \epsilon ].
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(1)$ note that as shown directly above the displayed formula with $(1)$ it was concluded using Step II that $\sum \Lambda h_i\geq \mu(K)$ holds.

Moreover, as $h_i \prec V_i$ we have $0\leq h_i \leq 1$ with $\mathrm{supp}(h_i)\subseteq V_i$ and so $\Lambda h_i \leq \mu(V_i)$ holds by definition of $\mu$. Then all remains to be done is to use the "defining measure inequality" for the $V_i$.

The main step in $(2)$ is probably using $$y_i-\varepsilon <y_{i-1}<f_{\mid E_i},$$
which shows that the first sum can be estimated by $\int_X f~\mathrm{d}\mu$.

For the second sum, one only estimates $y_i$ by $b$ and calculates the sum.

Comment: for step 2, how do we use the inequality to estimate the integral? because f is real and so the estimate by the definition of integral for simple functions seems to not be possible to be used

Comment: By $y_i-\varepsilon <f_{\mid E_i}$ we can conclude $(y_i-\varepsilon) \mu(E_i) \leq \int_{E_i} f ~\mathrm{d}\mu$ and then we use that the union of the $E_i$ is just $K$ which is the support of $f$.

Comment: how do you conclude the inequality for $E_i$?

Comment: On $E_i$ the function constant $y_i-\varepsilon$ is a function always smaller than $f$. By a general theorem on integration this also holds for the integrals (in general only with $\leq$ as we may look at zero sets).

Comment: Thanks that clears up the confusion